# node does not output using console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webstorm

I fairly new to nodejs and I put the following code in some module,

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/aa', function(req, res) {
        console.log("test");
        debugger;
        res.send('file updated');
...
```

the application is working and I see in the browser "file updated"
but I've two problems:

1. why don't I see "test" in the console?
2. I set up a debugger (using WebStorm 10) and it does not stop, what am I missing here?

I try also to run the debugger in Webstorm and click on debug and I see in the terminal *Debugger listening on port 55236* but when I change the port in the browser nothing happen, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Node runs server side, so any `console.log` statements will appear in the the console you ran your script from. You won't see any debug statements in the browser except those from client js code. The reason you see `file updated` is because you sent that string as a response to your browser, and its simply spitting back the response it got.
2. Same thing with the debugger. If you are using your browser's debugger, it will only affect client js code, NOT your server code. Not too familiar with WebStorm, but they have instructions for debugging Node.js specific code [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html)